# How can I add a new row into a dictionary of multiple items with the same key?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, size

I am working with a csv list, which has a approximately 7000 items, and it has certain keys, but I want to make a function that can add a new row to it, which comes from dividing the price with the weight and then sort the items based on that number.

I already have the number(price/weight), I did it with a for loop:

```
def ideal(dictionary):
    list2=list(dictionary)
    for x in range (len(list2)):
        Keys=list(dictionary[list2[x]])
        dict2=dictionary[list2[x]]
        column=list(map(dict2.get,Keys))
        newkey=(float(column[1]))/(float(column[2]))
```

I tried making a for loop, in order to insert the new row. The dictionary format looks like this:

```
'chips': {'category': 'food', 'price': '345.0', 'weight[kg]': '0.2',
'volume[m3]': '0.5545'}, 'broccoli': {'category': 'food', 'price': '449.0',
'weight[kg]': '2.72', 'volume[m3]': '0.5492'}, 'ham': {'category': 'food',
'price': '680.0', 'weight[kg]': '22.57', 'volume[m3]': '0.1359'}
}
```

There are more categories, ex: grocery

```
def ideal(dictionary):
    ####newkey is a float
    copy=dictionary
    for x in copy:
        dictionary.update( {"newkey":newkey})
```

But i get this error.

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: Do you mean `x.update(...)` in the last code section?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: You can't call iterate through a `dict` whilst you are updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy=dictionary` does not make a copy, but makes `copy` a reference to `dictionary` hence the error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` since you are modifying the dictionary while iterating it

Instead to make a copy you want to do `copy=dictionary.copy()`
You can then iterate over the dictionary and update the nested dictionary

```
def ideal(dictionary, newkey_list):
    #Make copy of dictionary
    copy=dictionary.copy()

    #Iterate through the dictionary
    for idx, value in enumerate(copy.values()):
        #Update nested dictionary with appropriate newkey
        value.update( {"newkey":newkey_list[idx]})
```

Comment: Now you've really done it, it worked perfectly, each value has its own coefficient, now I have to figure out how to sort them from biggest, to smallest based on that coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your `dict` contains nested `dict`s, you need to modify the subdict, not the outer one:

```
for key in copy:
    copy[key].update({'newkey': newkey})
```

As pointed out in other answers, to create a copy, use:

```
copy = dictionary.copy()
```

Although it may be better to use `copy.deepcopy()` as you have nested dictionaries.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it really worked. It's kind of confusing having a dict inside another dict haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `ideal()` with dict comprehension:

```
ideal_dict = {k: {**v, "new_key": v["old_key"] ** 2} for k, v in old_dict.items()}
```

Or if you want to update old dictionary:

```
old_dict.update({k: {**v, "new_key": v["old_key"] ** 2} for k, v in old_dict.items()})
```

*P.S. It should be faster.*